# Passing Props between components

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a bit of a playground to learn react and I've hit a road block with passing props between components. I essentially have two components, 1 that is the base component and then another that renders it out on the page with some extras (which i've removed for simplicity sake). I essentially want to be able to reuse the items in other places.

I'd like to be able to, when rendering the component in the example specify if it is `type=submit` if nothing specified default to `type=button`.

I'm clearly missing the point here because I get the error `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` with the below code. Any help would be appreciated

Button Component

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import './button_component.scss';

const propTypes = {
    type: PropTypes.string
}

const ButtonComponent = () => {
  return <button type={this.props.type}>button</button>
}

ButtonComponent.propTypes = propTypes;
export default ButtonComponent;
```

Then I have a component that outputs my item

```
import React from 'react';
import ButtonComponent from './button_component';
import Example from './example'

export default () =>
   <Example>
      <ButtonComponent type='button' />
   </Example>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ButtonComponent` is a [functional component](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components). Hence, you can not use `this.props` in its code.

You should introduce `props` argument

```
const ButtonComponent = (props) => {
  return <button type={props.type}>button</button>
}
```

Object destructuring and `defaultProps` can help you make your code simpler

```
const ButtonComponent = ({ type }) => {
  return <button type={type}>button</button>
}

ButtonComponent.defaultProps = {
  type: 'button'
}
```

then you can simply put `<ButtonComponent />` to render a button.

Comment: That was exactly my problem, thank you so much. Also thanks for the link explaining functional components that was really helpful!

Comment: @Ash note that there is a typo in your code. `type: propTypes.string` should be `type: PropTypes.string`